# Periodic-Rotating-File-Handler in yaml with Wildfly-Swarm not working

Tags: file, logging, handler, period, wildfly-swarm

I want to configura a periodic-rotating-file-handler to log into a debugfile using wildfly-swarm.
I want to do tgis using the project-defaults.yml

Currently I have the following:

```
swarm:
  logging:
    logging-profiles:
      root-logger:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers:
          - DEBUGFILE
          - CONSOLE
    periodic-rotating-file-handlers:
      DEBUGFILE:
        level: DEBUG
        enabled: true
        autoflush: true
        named-pattern: MY_PATTERN
        file:
          path: logs/debugfile.log
        suffix: .yyyy-MM-dd
     console-handlers:
      CONSOLE:
        level: DEBUG
        named-formatter: MY_PATTERN
    pattern-formatters:
      MY_PATTERN:
        pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p (%t) [%c] %s%e%n"
    loggers:
      de.myname:
        level: DEBUG
```

However, only the CONSOLE Logger gets registered and works as intended.
The log/debugfile.log gets created, but stays empty.
What can I do to fix this?
Also, the CONSOLE log-level is always on INFO. Only the `loggers.[de.myname].level` part enables classes in there to log on debug. Why isn't it always in debug like I said in `CONSOLE.level`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where the `logging-profiles` bit comes from, that sounds wrong. Also, since it's YAML, I think maybe `console-handlers` indentation might be wrong, but not sure about that.

Here's a snippet that I tested to work correctly a while ago:

```
swarm:
  logging:
    pattern-formatters:
      COLOR_PATTERN:
        pattern: "CUSTOM LOG FORMAT %p [%c] %s%e%n"
    periodic-rotating-file-handlers:
      FILE:
        file:
          path: target/foobar.log
        suffix: .yyyy-MM-dd
        named-formatter: COLOR_PATTERN
    root-logger:
      handlers:
      - CONSOLE
      - FILE
```

Comment: The `logging-profiles` bit comes from https://reference.wildfly-swarm.io/fractions/logging.html, I'll try without. I'll try your snipped, thank you

Comment: Your solution works, thank you. I think one of the Problems might have been, that I intended the list under root-logger.